# problem adding items to cart from outside magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, session

I'm having this problem and getting pretty annoyed by it.

here's the situation.

I was running a website on the codeigniter framework, and our customer wanted to add a shop to sell a couple of products. I decided to try to use magento, since its widely used and the documentation seemed ok.

My test setup on my local machine looks like this.

"localhost/project/" is the website root, where the codeigniter installation files are.

I added a new folder "store" to the root and installed magendo 1.9.2.2 into it. The magento installation runs as baseurl 127.0.0.1

Now i tried to add products from a codeigniter library to a magento cart via the following code:

```
require_once 'store/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

// Add a product with custom options
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $param);

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();
```

Seemed pretty straigforward. no errors or anything. I can verify that the adding works by

`$cart->getItemsQty();`

It shows the right amount of items.

But whenever I try to switch to the cart in the store itself using

`Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl()`

It is empty.

The interesting part is, I can get all the info I need from magento, but I cant seem to add anything to a cart.

Im guessing it has something to do with sessions getting mixed up.

**EDIT**:
`Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl()`
delivers something like

> http://127.0.0.1/project/store/index.php/checkout/onepage/?SID=5068c0335528f0713360cc3d6b302f8481ebb732

where as 5068c0335528f0713360cc3d6b302f8481ebb732 is the codeigniter session id. so im guessing the code never creates a magento session at all and links to a cart that with the CI session and not a magento session?

**EDIT2:**
i think im getting closer to the root of the problem. after printing the data for the magento session with
`echo print_r($session->getData());`

im getting the following

```
Array ( [_session_validator_data] => Array ( [remote_addr] => ::1 [http_via] => [http_x_forwarded_for] => [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36 ) [cart_was_updated] => 1 [id] => ) 1
```

the curious part for me is that the 'id' is empty. so i think the session is just not created correctly.

Comment: Did you try accessing the cart from codeigniter too ? My guess is it would be something like the session you create is not shared with Magento, and it is creating another one when you visit the URL.

Comment: @hellimac i followed up on your idea and you seem to be right. if i inspect the codeigniter session id "ci_session" and the "frontend" id they differentiate. but i CAN get the cart items from my codeigniter side. no idea what could cause this though.

Comment: @lagiacrux Did you achieve what you want?

Comment: @Rathinam no, if i remember correctly (it was 7 years ago), i stopped using magento and coded the shop application myself in php.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174789/how-to-call-magento-sessions-outside-magento

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of magento sessions while "outside magento" then you should use:

```
Mage::app()
```

instead of:

```
Mage::init()
```

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

Comment: thx for the reply. unfortunatly it didnt help..

Answer (score 0):

You need a formkey to add products to your cart. Try to get the formkey like this `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormkey`. This is needed in Magento 1.8 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to override cart controller addAction function and comment form key check then just have link from code igniter like http://host/
checkout/cart/add/product/id-of-the-product . up on click on the link will add the product to cart.