# How to call Magento sessions outside Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to call Magento cart and user sessions outside the Magento. I have to call sessions in core PHP project where i have to use Magento backend and core PHP project as frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for many hours i have got the solution. Below is the code which i have used to call the Magento sessions in custom PHP file from outside magento:

```
require_once ("/var/www/html/Magento/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");
umask(0);
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
```